# Count number of bits set to 1, why non-negative integers?

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

In Elements of Programming Interviews in Java, the authors say: "Writing a program to count the number of bits that are set to 1 in a nonnegative integer is a good way to get up to speed with primitive types".

Why do they qualify this with 'nonnegative'?

Answer (score 3):

Non-negative means positive or zero.

You are assumed to use shifts and bit operations.

Bit shifts can be sign-extending, which can be misleading. To avoid this issue, you are asked to handle non-negative values only.

But you can handle negative values too, if you want. Java has unsigned shifts `>>>`.

Sure this is an exercise. In real code you'll use a library implementation. `java.lang.Integer` has `bitCount(int i)`. I assume `bitCount` will execute on a hardware as bit-counting instruction, such as x86 `popcnt`, so it should be better than manual bit manipulation, or at least use a very decent bit manipulation implementation rather than one you'd write as an exercise. There's a whole tag [hammingweight](/questions/tagged/hammingweight) about counting those bits.

Comment: What do you mean by sign-extending?

Comment: @LP  compare the results of `0x80000000 >> 31` and `0x80000000 >>> 31` ,  the former populates bits from the left with sign, the later with zero, see https://ideone.com/xwrDc7

Answer (score 1):

Negative integers are stored a little bit differently.
In a 4 Bit signed integer, 1111b would be -1, whereas 1000b would be -8, making the count of 1's dependent on the number of bits in the number. That way you can't answer the question anymore.